# Why does the not operator on empty super() object deliver False?

Tags: python

As written in python documentation the `not` operator on an empty `dict` delivers `True`:

```
>>> print(not {})
True
```

But why is this not working if I do this on a super-class that is an empty `dict`:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...     def is_empty(self):
...         return not super(MyDict,self)
...     def is_empty2(self):
...         return not self
    
>>> a = MyDict()
>>> print(a.is_empty(), a.is_empty2())
False True
```

The same behavior we get if we use `bool()` instead.

Can somebody explain me why `super()` behaves in this case different as an empty `dict`?

Comment: Short version: Special method lookup done implicitly is typically done on the type. So `not super()` and `bool(super())` are looking for the class `super`'s implementation of `__bool__`, *not* the `__bool__` implemented on the class `super` is proxying. If you want this to work, you have to explicitly do `super().__bool__()` (or `not super().__bool__()` as needed). Of course, in this case, since you didn't override `__bool__`, `not self` works just fine, but if you had, you'd use `super().__bool__()` when you needed to skip to the parent's `__bool__`.

Comment: Because `super` objects are truthy, as are most objects unless they are implemented specifically to work another way.

Comment: Got it: super proxy object has a different `__bool__()` that is called, thanks!